# Dynamic relatedTo queries

Tags: entries

I've got an advanced search form which culminates in:

```
craft.entries.section('whatsOn').relatedTo(
    'and',
    { element: artCategories },
    { element: locationCategories },
    { element: bbfcCategories }
).search(searchTerm).order('score').limit(8)
```

This works, but only if the item being searched for has populated `artCategories`, `locationCategories`, and `bbfcCategories`.

Any of those are optional; i.e., the `bbfcCategories` line may not be needed at all... and likewise the searchTerm - is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the array for your criteria model's relatedTo parameter step for step before adding it:

```
{# Initial criteria model #}
{% set exhibitions = craft.entries.section('exhibitions').limit(null) %}

{# Compose relatedTo parameter #}
{% set relatedToParam = ['and'] %}

{% if query.art is defined %}
    {% set catIds = craft.categories.group('artCategories').id(query.art).ids() %}
    {% set relatedToParam = relatedToParam|merge([{ targetElement: catIds }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% if query.location is defined %}
    {% set catIds = craft.categories.group('locationCategories').id(query.location).ids() %}
    {% set relatedToParam = relatedToParam|merge([{ targetElement: catIds }]) %}
{% endif %}

{# Add additional criteria. Avoid passing an array with 'and' only #}
{% if relatedToParam|length > 1 %}
    {% set exhibitions = exhibitions.relatedTo(relatedToParam) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just adding a [link back to this post](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/filter-entries-on-a-page-based-on-related-entry/12141#12141), as it explains how you're setting `craft.request.getQuery()` and accessing it's parameter `query.art` (I haven't seen this method before). Does [`getQueryString()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQueryString) do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, this is right, `getQueryString()` returns the complete query string and `getQuery()` (without a param) returns the query string converted to an array.